# Javascript/Regex: Split() not working for my case

Tags: javascript, regex

My split() is not working when there is a space before or after each line in my variable. The code below should return (123,45,67,89) but instead it returns (1234567,89). The REGEX is the problem, probably, but I don't know how to fix it. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you,

```js
 var keywordsArray = "1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9";
    keywordsArray = keywordsArray.replace(/\s\s+/g,' ').split('\n');
    alert(keywordsArray);
```

Comment: Why dont you use __keywordsArray = keywordsArray.split('\n')__

Comment: Your regex also replaces new lines

Comment: Thank you Aman. That's it. I had to split first before removing extra spaces.

Comment: Ok, so I have checked your code as well and the only issue with your code is that \s is replacing \n as well try using only space ' '. This will make your statement to be something like this keywordsArray = keywordsArray.replace(/  +/g,' ').split('\n');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it worked with your string, may be this is the hard way... everything has a plan B

```js
var keywordsArray = "1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9";
keywordsArray = keywordsArray.split('\n').map(item => item.replace(/\s/g,''));
console.log(keywordsArray.join(','));
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below approaches.

#### Sepearted with , (comma):

```
> var result = keywordsArray.split('\n')
undefined
> result
[ '1 2 3  ', '4 5', ' 6       7', '8 9' ]
>
> result = result.map(s => s.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
[ '123', '45', '67', '89' ]
>
> result.join(',')
'123,45,67,89'
>
```

#### Array of integers:

```
> var keywordsArray = "1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9"
undefined
> keywordsArray
'1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9'
>
> var result = keywordsArray.split('\n')
undefined
> result
[ '1 2 3  ', '4 5', ' 6       7', '8 9' ]
>
> result = result.map(s => parseInt(s.replace(/\s+/g, '')))
[ 123, 45, 67, 89 ]
>
```

Comment: **@Creek**, I'm sorry for my mistake. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the regex pattern. First, remove all white space. After that, replace `\n` with `,`.

```
var keywordsArray = "1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9";
keywordsArray = keywordsArray.replace(/ */g,'').replace(/\n/g,',');
console.log(keywordsArray);
```

For more information about regex, check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is that `\s` is matching `\n` as well while `replace` statement, so instead of `\s` use space (' ').

Please find your code with just update mentioned above:

```js
var keywordsArray = "1 2 3  \n4 5\n 6       7\n8 9";
keywordsArray = keywordsArray.replace(/  +/g,' ').split('\n');
alert(keywordsArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the literal space ' ' instead of '\s' since

> /\s/g any whitespace character

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/) the next time you get stuck -- it's really helpful!